# Validating preexistence of items when transfering from a ListBox to ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox

In C# I have a ListBox and a ComboBox. I'm trying to transfer all my items from my ListBox to my ComboBox while checking if the items are already present on the ComboBox. Repeated items shouldn't get transfer, while the rest should be removed from the ListBox. I'm also meant to do the same transferring of items from the ComboBox into my ListBox.

I have everything almost done, however removing the transferred items is not working as it should as I'm present with some indexing issues.

My code when transferring from List to Cbx

```
String[] items = intoArrayLst(lstItem2);
ArrayList moved = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{

   if (!cbxItem.Items.Contains(items.ElementAt(i)))
   {
     cbxItem.Items.Add(items.ElementAt(i));
     moved.Add(items.ElementAt(i));
   }
}

for (int i = 0; i < lstItem2.Items.Count; i++)
{
   if(moved.Contains(lstItem2.Items.GetItemAt(i)))
   {
    lstItem2.Items.RemoveAt(i);                        
   }
}
```

From ComboBox to ListBox

```
String[] items = intoArrayCBX(cbxItem);
ArrayList moved = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
{
    if(!lstItem2.Items.Contains(items.ElementAt(i)))
    {
        lstItem2.Items.Add(items.ElementAt(i));
        moved.Add(items.ElementAt(i));
    }                        
}

for (int i = 0; i < cbxItem.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if(cbxItem.Items.Contains(moved[i]))
    {
        cbxItem.Items.RemoveAt(i);                        
    }                        
}
```

Would really appreciate some suggestions on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to avoid indexing issues when removing items from a list is to loop backwards through the list. That way the items that get index-shifted on a removal have already been processed.

```
for (int i = lstItem2.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (!cbxItem.Items.Contains(lstItem2.Items[i]))
    {
        cbxItems.Items.Add(lstItems2.Items[i]);
        lstItems2.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I always forget the power of the reverse loop. Thanks, been scratching my heads for hours thinking on this.